# Verify if a method of an object exists

Tags: coldfusion

I'm calling a web service through ColdFusion which returns an object, and I want to verify if one of the methods of this object exists as it won't always exist.

I found [this source](http://www.samfarmer.com/blog/using-structkeyexists-to-find-if-an-object-has-a-function) which seemed promising however based on my tests I can see the results are always negative and the method is never found when it's clearly there.

```
<cfif structKeyExists("#Result.getNotifications().getValidationResult(0)#","getField")>
```

`Result` is my underlying object, and my end goal is to verify if the method `getField()` exists.

[image]

Is there a clean way to do this as opposed to a try/catch?

Comment: Have you tried the `GetMetaData()` function? [GetMetaData documentation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7dd9.html) and [this](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/Developing/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7dc5.html#WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec0ac4a-7feb)

Comment: IDK if this helps, but the double quotes/hash marks should be unnecessary: <cfif structKeyExists(Result.getNotifications().getValidationResult(0),"getField")>

Answer (score 2):

**Update:**

Unfortunately, I am not sure `IsInstanceOf()` works with web services, due to the fact that CF uses a Proxy object to "wrap" the underlying web service class. If not, another simple option is to check class name. That avoids the ambiguity of checking for method name only (which could potentially exist in many different classes). Plus I suspect it may be more light-weight than `IsInstanceOf()` anyway.

```
<cfif compare(yourObject.getClass().name, "org.tempuri.ValidationResultField") eq 0>
   Found ValidationResultField. do something
</cfif>
```

---

It looks like the dump contains several different types of objects/classes: `ArrayOfValidationResult`, `ValidationResultField`, etecetera. It sounds like what you are really trying to determine is *which* of those classes you are working with, so you know exactly what fields and methods will be available, per the web service definitions. Given that, I think [IsInstanceOf()](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-functions/functions-in-k/isinstanceof.html) would be a more appropriate test, than checking for method names. More accurate as well. Nothing prevents two different classes from having the same method name. So even if method X or Y exists, there is still a possibility it *may* be a different class than expected.

```
<cfif IsInstanceOf(yourObject, "org.tempuri.ValidationResultField")>
     do something
</cfif>
```

Comment: I was trying to work that out - but I think you got it Leigh. If you really need to know if "getField()" Is there you can use toString() and then parse it. But that's probably worse than try/catch.

Comment: @MarkAKruger - Yes, I was thinking you could probably do something with reflection too, but it is still kind of ambiguous. Not to mention "getField()" is one of those generic names that probably exists in a *lot* of classes ;-)

Comment: You should prefer `getName()` over `name`. It's a private field.

Comment: @Alex - No, if the code were really trying to access a private field it would trigger an error, because it is .. well .. private. Check the docs, that shorthand is perfectly valid for javabean getters.

Comment: Where does the shorthand come from? It does throw an exception in Java, because `java.lang.Class` has a private field `name`. ;)

Comment: It is a bit of CF's [syntactic sugar](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/developing-applications/using-web-elements-and-external-objects/integrating-jee-and-java-elements-in-cfml-applications/using-java-objects.html) :)  *"...ColdFusion can automatically invoke get_PropertyName_() and set_PropertyName_(value) methods if a Java class conforms to the JavaBeans pattern. As a result, you can set or get the property by referencing it directly, without having to explicitly invoke a method."*

Comment: I see. I still dislike the idea of crippling Java just because CF has such questionable stuff, e.g. `yourObject.class.name` doesn't work because `getClass` is native. It's irritating and I strongly recommend sticking to Java conventions when working with Java classes.

Comment: Honestly, I use it a lot in debugging so the laziness of using the ".name" shortcut is habit. Though it really does not make much difference for just class "name". That has worked the same since CF7. I have never used it much beyond that. Not because it is annoying, simply because java and CF syntax are so similar. So sticking with method calls saves a lot of time, and makes for easier troubleshooting, when translating or mixing the two.

Comment: Hmmm, the issue is that the class `ValidationResultField` will always exist. It's essentially the property `Field` that may or may not exist. However I think I've found a work around. The object that is returned is in an XML format which means I could parse the XML and simply verify if the Field node exists. This is a last resort, but it's a sure way from what I can see. Now the question is, if these are my only options, is parsing XML or using the `reflect` class more efficient..

Comment: It seems I was mistaken, although the web service returns XML for some reason the function `XmlParse` returns `XmlParse(org.tempuri.ValidationCollection@23648ea1)`

Comment: *the issue is that the class ValidationResultField will always exist* I think you misunderstood. The check is not whether that class exists, but whether your `Result` object is an instance - of that class. Get the class name of your `Result` objects, ie `getValidationResult(0).getClass().name`. The value is a simple string. If it is equal to "org.tempuri.ValidationResultField", then you know that object contains the "getField" method.

Comment: Essentially you want to check the value displayed in the red headers of the dump image, ie "object of org.tempuri.ValidationResultField". That tells you what type of object you are dealing with.

Comment: *RE:...or using the reflect class more efficient*  While I initially thought it might work, as Alex's answer points out, it is just going to cause an error if the method does not exist. Since you still end up needing a try/catch anyway, reflection is pretty useless in this case. I would not bother with it.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, the mentioned `structKeyExists` approach only works if CF wraps the class internally, e.g. all instances of `cfcomponent`.

The only option left is to actually [reflect the class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getMethod-java.lang.String-java.lang.Class...-):

```
<cftry>
    <cfset Result.getNotifications().getValidationResult(0).getClass().getMethod("getField", javaCast("null", ""))>
    <!--- method does exist --->
    <cfcatch type="coldfusion.runtime.CfJspPage$UnsupportedBaseTypeException">
        <!--- method does not exist --->
    </cfcatch>
</cftry>
```

If the method doesn't exist, it throws `UnsupportedBaseTypeException`, which seems to be a follow-up of `NoSuchMethodException`.

Honestly, you might as well just invoke the method and catch it. Reflection comes with an additional overhead and you have to catch it anyway.

Comment: Alex - I was thinking about reflection (though not with a try/catch) but have not had a chance to try it uninterrupted. Does it actually work for any method names?

Comment: Yes, it does. It doesn't even matter if you pass parameters (that's the second param, `null`), but it will throw `NoSuchMethodException` on an unknown method regardless.

Comment: Okay. I am familiar with it, but when I gave it a very quick spin earlier it crashed. Just wanted to make sure it was due to my own distraction, and not that something had changed in CF11+.

Comment: I tested it in CF10 (as this is the target version I'm working with on a daily base), so not sure if it works beyond that.

Comment: No, you are right. It works fine. My brain is just fried. I have used it before, but usually with methods that *do* exist. I was expecting it to throw one of the declared exceptions (not cf.runtime), and not until the non-existent method was invoked. Guess if it is just going to throw an exception you end up having to handle anyway, it makes using reflection kind of pointless.

Answer (score 0):

In general, you may obtain the metadata of all the functions of a webservice, given the URL of the WSDL, with something like

```
<cfhttp method="get" url="http://www.webservicex.net/globalweather.asmx?WSDL" result="res">
<cfset wsXml=xmlparse(res.filecontent)>
<cfset wsOperations = xmlsearch(wsXml,"//wsdl:operation")>
<cfdump var="#wsOperations#">
```

Another method you could look at (perhaps undocumented) is to get the method names from the class names in the stubs directory.

The code to run is:

```
<cfscript>
wsargs = structnew();
wsargs.savejava="yes";
</cfscript>
<cfset convert=createobject("webservice","url_of_wsdl",wsargs)>
```

Then figure out how to fish out the names from the stubs directory, {CF_INSTALL}/stubs. In my case, CF_INSTALL is C:/ColdFusion2016/cfusion/

Comment: That does not answer the question of whether a specific *instance* contains a particular method.

Comment: This answer just saved my day!!!!

Answer (score 0):

I received an e-mail update on this today. Looking at it anew, I would suggest the following solution:

```
<cfset arrayOfMethods=testWSObject.getClass().getMethods()>  
<cfset arrayOfMethodNames=arrayNew(1)>  
<cfoutput>  
<cfloop from="1" to ="#arrayLen(arrayOfMethods)#" index="i">    
    <cfset methodName=arrayOfMethods[i].getName()>  
    Name of method #i#: #methodName#<br>    
    <cfset arrayAppend(arrayOfMethodNames,methodName)> 
</cfloop> 
</cfoutput>
<p>
<cfoutput>Does class have method called 'getID'?: #arrayContains(arrayOfMethodNames, 
"getID")#</cfoutput>`
```

Answer (score -1):

Like Miguel-F, I think this is something for getMetadata(). The following should return an array containing the respective functions of the object:

```
<cfset funcs = getmetadata(nameOfObj).functions>
```

The names of the functions are then funcs[1].name, funcs[2].name, and so on.

Comment: That is for components (and other supported objects). A webservice is not a component.

Comment: Say what! "A webservice is not a component"??!! You are wrong!

Comment: Google: coldfusion webservice component

Comment: Yes, tested. it works as expected. I saw the distinction you made.The object in question is createobject("component","path_to_component"), not createobject("webservice","url_of_webservice"). In any case, I am assuming the CFC is yours.

Comment: *Yes, tested. it works as expected* No, you tested something different. The OP is using `createobject("webservice")` to consume an external web service. If you look at the dumps in the OP, the returned object is *not* a component, and getMetaData does not work on that type of object.

Comment: What I am saying is, if you have access to the component, then you will be able to get the functions from the component object rather than from the webservice object.

Comment: Again, look at the dump. This particular web service is *not* a CF component.